# (C#) iterate over read-only private collection member

Tags: c#, iteration, hashset, private-members

I have a class which has two `HashSet<String>` collections as private members.  Other classes in my code would like to be able to iterate over those HashSets and read their contents.  I don't want to write a standard getter because another class could still do something like `myClass.getHashSet().Clear();`  Is there any other way to expose the elements of my HashSets to iteration without exposing the reference to the HashSet itself?  I'd love to be able to do this in a way that is compatible with for-each loops.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, esp. Strager for the most complete answer, and Jon Skeet for cleaning up my OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose a `IEnumerable<T>` property:

```
public IEnumerable<whatevertype> MyHashSet {
    get {
        return this.myHashSet;
    }
}
```

Of course, the user of this code can cast that `IEnumerable<T>` to a `HashSet<T>` and edit elements, so to be on the safe side (while hurting performance), you can do:

```
public IEnumerable<whatevertype> MyHashSet {
    get {
        return this.myHashSet.ToArray();
    }
}
```

or:

```
public IEnumerable<whatevertype> MyHashSet {
    get {
        foreach(var item in this.myHashSet) {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

A more performant method of protection, but less convenient to the caller, is to return an `IEnumerator<T>`:

```
public IEnumerator<whatevertype> GetMyHashSetEnumerator() {
    return this.myHashSet.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Why even present the `ToArray` option? The iterator block is more performant and does not consume additional memory (other than for the setup of the compiler-generated stub class.)

Comment: I think the yield approach is cleanest, as it's lazy-executed and shouldn't use up more memory. I haven't measured it though.

Comment: Interesting question: does `yield return` work faster than `ToArray()`?

Comment: It's *a* method, not *the* method, and there are probably better methods out there.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5, one alternative to writing the yield code yourself is to call a LINQ method. For example:

```
public IEnumerable<string> HashSet
{
    get { return privateMember.Select(x => x); }
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<string> HashSet
{
    get { return privateMember.Skip(0); }
}
```

There are various LINQ operators which could be used like this - using `Skip(0)` is probably the most efficient, as after the initial "skip 0 values" loop, it's probably just the `foreach`/`yield return` loop shown in the other answers. The `Select` version will call the no-op projection delegate for each item yielded. The chances of this difference being significant are astronomically small, however - I suggest you go with whatever makes the code clearest to you.

Comment: +1. I'd go with `Skip` to avoid the unnecessary lambda overhead. While it's not terribly substantial, it doesn't really get you anything here.

Answer (score 3):

Add a method/property like this to avoid exposing the actual container:

```
public IEnumerable EnumerateFirst()
{
     foreach( var item in hashSet )
         yield return item;
}
```

Comment: Better, as this stops /really/ obnoxious callers casting the IEnumerable back to a HashSet. However, you're not strongly typing the IEnumerable, which may not be such a good thing.

Comment: +1. While others are advocating exposing the member only as an `IEnumerable<T>` (and this will, in a strict sense, accomplish what you want), that is not a safe practice. While the object itself is being exposed only as the interface, there's nothing stopping an enterprising developer from casting your object back to the `HashSet`. The practice here is safer, since you never expose the actual `HashSet` reference.

Comment: @strager: Marginally at best.

Comment: I agree that it should be strongly typed (using IEnumerable<T>), but OP did not provide element type information so I kept the example simple.

Comment: @Morten: `HashSet` exists only as a generic type in .NET (`Hashtable` is the older, non-generic type), so it's probably a little clearer to use the appropriate `IEnumerable<T>`, though that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Morten: Actually the type was present in the source - just hidden by markdown :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `Select` method to create a wrapper than can't be cast back to `HashSet<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Values
{
    get { return _values.Select(value => value);
}
```

This avoids iterating over `_values` twice, as you would with `.ToArray()`, but keeps the implementation to a single clean line.

Answer (score 1):

This might be quite a bit too late to the party but the easiest way today would be to use Linq. Instead of writing

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetValues() 
{
    foreach(var elem in list)
        yield return elem; 
}
```

you can write

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetValues() => list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also provide a sequence like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetHashSetOneValues()
{
    foreach (string value in hashSetOne)
        yield return value;
}
```

This method may then be called within a foreach loop:

```
foreach (string value in myObject.GetHashSetOneValues())
    DoSomething(value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your getter expose the HashSet as IEnumerable.

```
private HashSet<string> _mine;

public IEnumerable<string> Yours
{
    get { return _mine; }
}
```

If the generic type is mutable, then that can still be modified, but no items can be added or removed from your HashSet.

Comment: Yes they can - the caller just has to cast back to `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: Ok, but then there's no guarantee of safety in any respect.  Even if _mine is a private instance member, you can get at it using reflection.  If the consumer chooses to violate the contract provided by the API, then they must accept the consequence of doing so.  By exposing it as an `IEnumerable<T>`, you're making it obvious that the consumer should only be iterating, and not modifying your collection.  Isn't that good enough?

Comment: By common convention, not usually. There's a big difference between casting and reflection-based private member access.

Comment: I'm not arguing against the difference, just against over-engineering the solution.  In most cases, hiding your concrete type behind an interface in a getter is sufficient.  If I were a code reviewer and I saw the more "secure" solutions, I would be forced to ask if there were a solid case for going the extra mile.  Most likely the answer would be "no."

Comment: Everyone's certainly entitled to an opinion and their own practices, to be sure. It just appears (based upon the votes) that the community disagrees with you.